Error installing public keys in docker container without gnupg, but can't install gnupg without keys
I'm having to upgrade a docker container from a node:16-slim to a node:18-slim base. I've been having issues so have cut the dockerfile back to absolute basics, but still can't get it to work when running through my gitlab pipeline.
This is the first (incredibly brief) dockerfile:
FROM node:18-slim

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 6ED0E7B82643E131 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys F8D2585B8783D481 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 54404762BBB6E853 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys BDE6D2B9216EC7A8

This gives me the error "gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation", so I try to add gnupg2 (I've also tried gnupg and gnupg1, out of interest, same issue):
FROM node:18-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 6ED0E7B82643E131 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys F8D2585B8783D481 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 54404762BBB6E853 && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys BDE6D2B9216EC7A8

And now I get the issue that prompted me to add the keys in the first place:
> [2/3] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2:
0.375   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
0.377 Reading package lists...
0.385 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
0.385 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
0.385 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
0.385 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
0.385 W: GPG error: http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
0.385 E: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease' is not signed.
0.385 E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
0.386 E: Sub-process returned an error code

So it seems I need the public keys to do an apt-get update, but I need gnupg for that, and to install that, I need to do apt-get update. This is all feeling very circular.
Can anyone offer some insight? Thanks!

The public keys for the standard Debian repositories should be embedded in the image already.  Are you in some sort of network environment with a proxy that forges encrypted traffic?  Have you accidentally overwritten the official node image with something you've built yourself (does docker pull node:18-slim help)?

Plus apt-key has been obsolete since about 2020 (replaced by separate files in /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d) and sks-keyservers.net stopped working 3 years ago (Hagrid + GPDR) -- there are multiple Qs about both of these on stacks where they are ontopic, not here

@DavidMaze thanks for the thoughts. No, nothing fancy, and nothing is overwritten. Pulling the image first does nothing to help.
I notice that the logs show that, when I use node:16-slim, it's using "http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease" but with 18+, it's using "http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease". I've tried node:18-slim, node:20-slim, node:22-slim, and the full images, too. All behave in an identical way. But anything 16 or below works fine.
My dockerfile is now down to two lines:
FROM node:18-slim
RUN apt-get update
Hoping to get to the bottom of this, soon!
